# React setState don't saving List of components that acess localStorage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, local-storage, react-state

My project is a Stopwatch written in typescript, using React and restore last session with the **localStorage**'s browser. Detail of functionalities on the [git repo](https://github.com/diassisfilho/nexus-advanced-stopwatch-web) [README.md](https://github.com/diassisfilho/nexus-advanced-stopwatch-web#readme). The states **stopwatches**, **restoredStopwatches** and **sessionRestored** on *src/Stopwatch/controller.tsx* are not updating correcty on React's `setSate()`.

Principally the **restoredStopwatches** state are not updating when using Stopwatch component on *src/Stopwatch/index.tsx* (Therefore this the restore of last sessions are not working fully, just set on stopwatch). I have tested with other test simple component and runned perfectly. The others states are not working on looking the chrome's debugger runnig.

### Declaration of states (*src/Stopwatch/controller.tsx*)

```
  const [stopwatches, setStopwatches] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([]);
  const [restoredStopwatches, setRestoredStopwatches] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([]);
  const [sessionRestored, setSessionRestored] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

### Use example of setState

```
  function restoreStopwatch(uuid: string) {
    const lastUnusedSessionsUUIDs = getLastUnusedSessionsUUIDs(
      getLastSessionsUUIDs()
    );
    if (
      lastUnusedSessionsUUIDs.find(
        (lastUnusedSessionUUID) => uuid === lastUnusedSessionUUID
      )
    ) {
      console.log(`not restored stopwatch, with uuid ${uuid}, not used`);
    } else {
      setRestoredStopwatches([
        ...restoredStopwatches,
        <Stopwatch key={uuid.slice(5, 8)} uuid={uuid} />,
      ]);
      console.log(`restored stopwatch, with uuid ${uuid}`);
    }
  }
```

I think that is because the Stopwatch access **localStorage** and the component **is heavy** to the setState run on correctly time (even being asynchronous).

I tried to moved code from *src/App.tsx* to *src/components/Stopwatch/controller.tsx* expecting turn less heavy the code, but not worked on.

Comment: It's very strange to be adding react components to your state like that

Comment: @turtlepick have some links of tutorials or anything that suggests another way?